# Redirect if user has acces level 2 or higher

Tags: php, mysql

So I am making an simple PHP project and I dont have much exprience with PHP.

Maybe you guys can help me out.

I have a database wich stores user crendentials, which looks like this.

```
id|Username|Password|          Mail       |Acces|
1 |Josh    | *****  |Something@hotmail.com|  1  |
2 |Rick    | **0**  |Generalpo@hotmail.com|  2  |
```

And on my php page I want to make it so if the Acces level out of the database is higher then 1 it does a redirect. I am doing it with echo's right know so i don't get redirected all the time. But every time i do this i just get i dont have enough rights. while i am logging in with the Username Josh.

```
$sql = "SELECT * From login Where Username= "'$_SESSION('username')'"";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql));
if ($row['Acces'] == "1"){
Echo("You have enough rights");
}else{
Echo("You dont have enough rights");
};
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You're currently checking if the accesslevel is equal to "1". You should modify this to > (higher than).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it partially right, but I would make some changes:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'");
$sql_fetched = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if ($sql_fetched['Acces'] > 1)
{
    echo "You have enough rights and will be redirected automatically.";
    header('refresh:3;url=redirect.php');
}
else
{
    echo "You dont have enough rights.";
    header('refresh:3;url=login.php');
}
```

Comment: Still an unhealthy amount of SQL injection going on, and unless `$_SESSION` is somehow a function in your system, this will not work.

Comment: Yes It worked, checked both accounts and know the do the redirect and the message appears!
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * From login Where Username= "'$_SESSION('username')'"";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql));
if ($row['Acces'] == "1"){
header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); /* Redirect browser */
}else{
echo('You dont have enough rights');
};
```

Change http://www.example.com/ to your desired one.

Comment: Header with `Location` needs an absolute URI, not just `somewhere.php`

Comment: Firstly, you're using `'` to concat the string? `.` is the correct operator in PHP. Secondly, you're using `(` and `)` to access the `$_SESSION` array, *even though*, the way to access arrays in PHP is through brackets `[` and `]`. I know this is just pasted from the OP, but you should've corrected it.

Comment: Oh, too sleepy. I'm sorry.
`header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); /* Redirect browser */`

Comment: @S.Visser Yes - it's still morning here in Denmark, so you'll have to excuse my typos. :-)

Comment: I hope this answers your question accurately.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` Where `Username`='{$_SESSION['username']}'";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
    if ($row['Acces'] == "1") {
        // Change these two headers to the file you want to redirect too
        header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/enoughrights.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/notenough.php");
    }
}
```